# Completeness and orthogonal projection

Tags: functional-analysis, orthogonality, complete-spaces

> a. Which are the properties that define an orthogonal projection? Give a precise definition.
>
> b. What does completeness mean? Please state both the definition and an example (without proof) of a complete vector space.

Can someone give these  precise definitions please ?

Regarding a) I know it orthogonal if it

1. Is linear
2. Is idempotent.

B) I don't have clue about it.

Comment: Do you know what is a complete metric space? Any notion of Cauchy sequence, convergent sequence?

Comment: A complete metric space is a metric space in which every Cauchy sequence is convergent.

Comment: A clue for self study, for the noun in mathematics (orthogonal projection, complete vector space) you don't know, search it on wiki, there a short lecture for you to learn

Comment: A projector acting in a Hilbert space is orthogonal if also a third condition, it being self-adjoint (Hermitean) is satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Definition [Orthogonal Projection]:** Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a real or complex Hilbert space, and let $M$ be a closed subspace of $\mathcal{H}$. The orthogonal projection $P_{M} : \mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ maps $x\in\mathcal{H}$ to the unique $P_{M}x \in M$ such that
>   $$
>                      (x-P_{M}x) \perp M.
> $$
>   (That is, $\langle x-P_{M}x,m\rangle=0$ for all $m\in M$.)

To see that $P_M$ is well-defined, suppose $(x-m)\perp M$ and $(x-m')\perp M$ for some $m,m'\in M$. Then $m-m'=(x-m')-(x-m)$ is orthogonal to itself, making $m-m'=0$.

One can show that orthogonal projection is the same as closest point projection onto $M$. Closest point projection exists because $M$ is a complete subspace. So orthogonal projection is everywhere defined, and these two projections map $x$ to the same $m \in M$.

**Linearity:** Orthogonal projection is *automatically linear* because of uniqueness, and the fact that
$$
    (x-P_Mx)\perp M,\;\;(y-P_{M}y)\perp M \\
  \implies \{(\alpha x+\beta y)-(\alpha P_{M}x+\beta P_{M}y)\} \perp M.
$$
**Idempotent:** $P_{M}$ is the identity on $M$ because $(m-m)\perp M$. Therefore $P_{M}^2=P_{M}$.

**Symmetry:** $
   \langle P_{M}x,y\rangle  = \langle P_{M}x,(y-P_{M}y)+P_{M}y\rangle
        = \langle P_{M}x,P_{M}y\rangle.$
Hence,
$$
      \langle P_{M}x,y\rangle = \langle P_{M}x,P_{M}y\rangle = \langle x,P_{M}y\rangle.
$$
**Bounded:** $\|x\|^2=\|x-P_{M}x\|^2+\|P_{M}x\|^2 \ge \|P_{M}x\|^2$.

Conversely, if $P=P^2=P^{\star}$ is linear, then you can show that $P$ satisfies the properties of an orthogonal projection onto $M=P\mathcal{H}$ because
\begin{align}
 \langle x-Px,m \rangle
       & = \langle x-Px,Pm \rangle \\
       &= \langle P^{\star}(x-Px),m\rangle \\
       &= \langle P(x-Px),m\rangle \\
       &= \langle Px-P^2x,m\rangle = 0,\;\;\; m \in M.
\end{align}

> **Definition [Complete]:** Let $X$ be normed linear space over the real or complex numbers. A sequence $\{ x_n \} \subset X$ is a Cauchy sequence if, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that $\|x_n-x_m\| < \epsilon$ whenever $n,m \ge N$. $X$ **complete** if every Cauchy sequence in $X$ has a limit in $X$.

**Example:** $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is complete.

Answer (score 0):

A. Your properties are characterized for projection, not orthogonal. A mapping $p :E \rightarrow E $ is orthogonal projection if $p$ is linear, idempotent, and $<x-p(x),p(y)>= \, \forall x,y \in E$ ($<,>$ is denoted for scalar products in $E$)

B. Completeness property is "Every Cauchy sequences is converged". Informally, if you have a sequence look so close at the end, it eventually got a limit in your space. For example, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete, take the sequence 1, 1.4, 1.414, ...  It converges to $\sqrt{2}$ which is well known that irrational. $\mathbb{R}$ is complete and it is completion of $\mathbb{Q}$